# how can i use openMP for my code?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm beginning in openMP and i want parallelize this portion of code

```
int A[n][m+1];
int B[k][m];
for (h=0;h<100;h++){
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){p=0;
        for (j=0;j<k;j++){s=0;
            for (l=0;l<m;l++){
                 s+=(A[i][l]-B[j][l]);
             }
          s=sqrt(s);    
          if (j==0) min =s;
           else
            if (min > s){min =s;p=j;}              
       }
    A[i][m]=p;
    }
}
```

and this is my attempt for parallelize using openMP

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(s)
 for (h=0;h<100;h++){
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){p=0;
        for (j=0;j<k;j++){s=0;
            for (l=0;l<m;l++){
                 s+=(A[i][l]-B[j][l]);
             }
          s=sqrt(s);    
          if (j==0) min =s;
           else
            if (min > s){min =s;p=j;}              
       }
    A[i][m]=p;
    }
}
```

how can i do this correctly? i need your help.

Comment: What do you think you're doing wrong?

Comment: First properly indent your code and add white space.  Don't use variable name `l` as it is hardly distinguishable from `1`; it's asking for problems.

Comment: Maybe `h, i,j,p,l` and `min` should be private too : each thread should handle its own value of `h,i,j,l` and `min`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple aspects you are missing right now:

**Private vs. shared variables:** you must not have several threads use the same variable as loop counters or any other kind of auxiliar variable. If one threads modifies the loop counter of another thread, then chaos ensues. Solution: specify which variables  are shared and which are private:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(s, min, h, i, j, l) shared(n, k, m)
```

**Reduction**: you are carrying out a reduction operation on the variable 'min'. Starting at OpenMP 3.1 and gcc 4.7 you can have OpenMP handle this reduction for you (*):

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(min : min) private(s, h, i, j, l) shared(n, k, m)
// here the rest of your code
```

This particular piece of syntax is obscured by the name of both the operation `min` (minimum) and your `min` variable being the same. Right now I'm not sure if you really need to change the name of the variable -I assume you don't need to-, but it's a good idea nevertheless. Also, as you have already been told in the comments, try to avoid the use of letter 'l' as a variable name, because it looks like the digit 1.

(*) In earlier versions of OpenMP in C you didn't have min/max reductions, so you would have had to store a temporary value for `min` in each thread's private variable, and then find the global min after the loop, inside a critical section or using atomic operations.